# Is this a Morus alba seedling?

Tags: identification, trees, mulberry

They are everywhere. Their leaf underbelly is glabrous; the indentations or lobes still not there... Alternate leaves. The seedlings are ubiquitous in the suburbs, and unfortunately the grown-up trees as well.

Just want to make sure this is what it is.

[image]

Comment: I'm leaning toward Morus rubra based on nothing more than a feeling about the robustness of the leaves - which tend to be thicker than alba. BUT can you take photos of the adult leaves? That would help more. Incidentally, why don't you like the mulberry trees?

Comment: Hi Antoni! I know nothing about trees, so this comment is based solely on a web search which says that the leaf of the alba is generally glabrous (hairless) underneath, as you've mentioned about yours. @ThatIdiot has first-hand knowledge, and is much more likely to be correct, so when you take photos of the adult leaves, please include the underside. Bark color/texture are identifiers too, so if you can get us a picture of the trunk of a grown tree, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At this stage it can be tricky to say, but based on your location, and the pic you provided, this does appear to be [*Morus rubra*](http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=58). Or, also very likely, a hybrid between *M. rubra* and [*M. alba*](http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=527), which are becoming extremely common in the northeast, and is helping spread the invasive Asian white mulberry (*M. alba*) out of control.